# Old Visioneer 5800 on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, scanner, twain

Does anyone know of a way to get an old Visioneer 5800 scanner that's supposed to work with nothing past Windows XP SP1 to work on Windows 7 64-bit?  I don't care about all the bells and whistles, just the basic features.  Is there any kind of generic TWAIN interface that can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)** with USB support and setup a virtual machine with 32-bit XP.

other than virtualization, there is no way to get this dinosaur working with Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Thanks, finally got around to playing with this.  Works perfectly.  I've just got an extreme minimalist install of XP inside a VM (4GB HD, 192 MB RAM), and I save the state and open it when I need it.